# Is it possible to install on Try Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, package-management

I am new to the Linux world. I'm hoping to move from windows to Linux in the foreseeable future and I will like to know how to if possible, install any wireless drivers before installing Ubuntu. Specifically, I want to install drivers for the TP-Link TL-WN823N drivers. My main goal is to try Ubuntu and install the wireless drivers before going through the installation so that I can then download the third party software. Is it possible to do this? If so what tools do I readily require before doing such a task?